# MacBook Air 2013 model A1466 after sleeping issues

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, sleep-wake

My MacBook Air 2013 does not wake up after sleeping for 7 hours. I reset SMC by pressing the Shift, Control, Option and power button all together for 10 seconds and it does not respond and nothing appears on the screen.

Now the respond I’m doing to my MacBook Air is to drain the battery for the couple of hours then plugged in the charger and try those steps i have done earlier. So far I don’t know what should i do?

Comment: Can you turn your MacBook on at this point?